# RuntimeError when importing PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am learning PyQt5 now

When I tried to run the following code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
```

I meat the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-10-0ebe4054b7ae>", line 1, in <module>
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
RuntimeError: the PyQt5.QtCore and PyQt4.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class
```

So what's wrong? thx for help!

Comment: [parts of both PyQt4 and PyQt5 are being imported at some point](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/pull/483). You should be able to reproduce the same error in two lines: `from PyQt4.QtCore import QObject` and `from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject`.

Comment: I used another laptop running my previous code and it did not meet the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Matplotlib Uses QT5 and you are using QT4. To solve the problem, you can force Matplotlib to use QT4, by editing matplotlibrc, which is situated in \Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data

In my case it was matplotlib [image]

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306186/pycharm-pyqt4-pyqt5-collision-in-debug-mode) solved my issue:

you can go to Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Debugger>Python Debugger>PyQt compatible: Select PyQt4.