# PyCharm PyQt4 / PyQt5 collision in debug mode

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt, pycharm, pyqt4

I am trying to use PyQt4 in pycharm. My code works perfectly in run mode, but in debug mode, when I try to import PyQt4 I get the following error:

*"RuntimeError: the PyQt4.QtCore and PyQt5.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class"*

This happens even w/ very barebones code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
print('cheese')
```

(thus, this is different from [previous](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000551170-PyQt4-and-PyQt5-collisions-in-PyCharm-2017-2-1-when-debugging-QGIS-application) PyQt4 Pycharm problems w. Matplotlib)

Clearly, the PyCharm debugger is using PyQt5 (this can be seen by calling sys.modules['PyQt5']). How can I 'un-import' PyQt5, or at least prevent the collision?

Also: I tried importing differently to include explicit dependencies, but this also gives error:

```
import PyQt4 as pp
pp.QtGui
```

*AttributeError: module 'PyQt4' has no attribute 'QtGui'*

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can go to Settings>Build,Execution,Deployment>Debugger>Python Debugger>PyQt compatible:
Select PyQt4.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to File > Settings > Project > Project Interpreter.  Edit your current interpreter, or create a new one, and remove PyQt5 from the list that shows up.

Comment: PyQt5 actually doesnt show up there since I think its not an actual project package but a tool PyCharm implicitly uses in debug mode (eg its not used during run mode)